# How to eliminate trailing comma in CSV output of Jasper

Tags: java, csv, jasper-reports

My jasper data source is JRBeanCollectionDataSource and input is following collection.
[SampleData [SerialNo=1,code=123,price=20],SampleData [SerialNo=2,code=234,price=20]].

Code snippet :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="custom" language="groovy" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="2a3860b7-4c46-41ea-aae9-7f02e3679927">
        <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
        <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
        <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="SerialNo" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[SerialNo]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="code" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[code]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="price" class="java.lang.Long">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[price]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <title>
            <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="22" height="20" uuid="5fc7b8ea-a635-4997-802e-82f3e06c8694"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[HDR]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="22" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="f653a4ef-7863-4ea2-bb52-0cfa38d26ef0"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{price}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="152" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="409ca2ad-ccf8-4007-bf41-ca67fee156fe"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[Rupees]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </title>
        <detail>
            <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="22" height="20" uuid="5fc7b8ea-a635-4997-802e-82f3e06c8694"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[BDY]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="22" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="f653a4ef-7863-4ea2-bb52-0cfa38d26ef0"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{SerialNo}!=null?$F{SerialNo}:"-"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="152" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="ed37edb9-bb8f-43bf-904f-6ca5b5941aea"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{code}!=null?$F{code}:"-"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </detail>
        <summary>
            <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="22" height="20" uuid="5fc7b8ea-a635-4997-802e-82f3e06c8694"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[TRL]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="22" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="adcc7751-da03-4141-9045-821960ce77c7"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </summary>
    </jasperReport>
```

It gives me output as below.

```
HDR,20,Rupees
BDY,1,123
BDY,2,234
TRL,2,
```

But I do not want trailing comma at trailer part. Output should be as follows.

```
HDR,20,Rupees
BDY,1,123
BDY,2,234
TRL,2
```

Comment: I believe that JR could not help you in solving this task. You should write some Java code. BTW, what is a right result for `BDY,,123` row in your logic?

Comment: How are you exporting this code? I assume from the output that it's probably CSV but you've not specified which makes it hard to advise correctly. If this is the case then, as Alex K says, it will have to be handled with a Java script, as it's not a direct Jasper issue.